# Correct word for area inside and outside a property?

Tags: single-word-requests

My native language is Swedish. And I work as a webdeveloper. And at the moment I am working on a real estate website written in English.

A word that describes the area inside a property. For this I think the word "Living Area" is best (but please correct me if I am wrong). But what about a word that descibes the total area outside of the property (like, garden etc etc)?

Edit: I am looking for the word in US-EN.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yard -- (but wait for confirmation from a US member)

Comment: I think this is the wrong word I am looking for. Think of if it is a farm or a mansion. Whith huge lands or forest or huge backyard. (all land included with the property) would for example "yard" be a good word for describing the lands of a farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your comment, I think you can use:

***[Ground (s)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ground) :***

> - (often grounds) The land surrounding or forming part of a house or another building:
>
>   - *a guesthouse on the grounds of the mansion.*

The Free Dictionary

[image]

Gardens and estate grounds.

Comment: Do you think I could use Ground Area? Or should I only go with "Grounds"?

Comment: I'd go with 'grounds'.

Comment: "Grounds" normally refers to the property of quite a large house or estate, as in the photo.  Typical middle-class homeowners, for example, do not refer to their front-yard and back-yard combined as their "grounds", except ironically.  So "grounds" would apply perfectly to certain properties on the real estate website, but not to others.

Comment: *Property* is also used to refer to a parcel of land, small or large.

Comment: Do you have a better idea then Grounds Tim?

Answer (score 0):

There is a term little used outside the legal domain:

**curtilage** {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtilage)}

> In law, the curtilage of a house or dwelling is the land immediately
>   surrounding it, including any closely associated buildings and
>   structures, but excluding any associated "open fields beyond", and
>   also excluding any closely associated buildings, structures, or
>   divisions that contain the separate intimate activities of their own
>   respective occupants with those occupying residents being persons
>   other than those residents of the house or dwelling of which the
>   building is associated.[citation needed] It delineates the boundary
>   within which a home owner can have a reasonable expectation of privacy
>   and where "intimate home activities" take place. It is an important
>   legal concept in certain jurisdictions for the understanding of search
>   and seizure, conveyancing of real property, burglary, trespass, and
>   land use planning.
>
> In urban properties, the location of the curtilage may be evident from
>   the position of fences, wall and similar; within larger properties it
>   may be a matter of some legal debate as to where the private area ends
>   and the "open fields" start.

But 'grounds' is probably the safer option. Both legally, and for user-friendliness.